# Understanding how for an infinite set $a$, $h(f)=(g(f\upharpoonright n),f(n))$ defines a bijection from $^{n+1}a$ onto $a\times a$

Tags: induction, set-theory, proof-explanation, recursion

This is from a proof in "Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic," pages 48-49 using induction and transfinite recursion. I am trying to see how things work in this instance.

It is a proof that:

> > If for any set $a$ and $n\in \omega\setminus\{0\}$, $a^n$ is defined as $a^1:=a$ and $a^{k+1}:=a^k\times a$, then we have for any infinite set $a$:
> >
> > $|a|=|a\times a|=|a^n|$ and $|^{n}a|=|a|$

The proof proceeds asserting that $a^n$ and $^{n}a$ are sets of all $n$-tuples of members of $a$. And assumes

> > as inductive hypothesis that $g$ is a bijection from $^{n}a$ onto $a$.

Here is the transfinite recursion to which my question pertains:

> > then $h(f)=(g(f\upharpoonright n),f(n))$ defines a bijection from $^{n+1}a$ onto $a\times a$.

I was trying to see how things work in a specific case, say $n=4$, to get $^{3+1}a=a\times a$.

Using the induction hypothesis for $n=3$, $g(3)$ is a bijection from $a\times a\times a=^{3}a$ onto $a$.

From here on I am lost. I can pose several questions:

-- is $h(f)$ a function from $g(f\upharpoonright n)$ to $f(n)$ or something that becomes clear based on the following question

-- what would $f\upharpoonright n$ and $f(n)$ and $g(f\upharpoonright n)$ be.

Then perhaps I can see the bijection from $^{3+1}a$ onto $a\times a$. I presume the $a$ in the first position corresponds to the induction hypothesis of the bijection from $^{3}a$ onto $a$.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that here $f$ is a function from $n+1$ to $a$. So it's not $g(3)$, but rather $g(a_0,a_1,a_2)$.

This is really the "obvious" way of doing that. Composing the bijection between $a\times a$ and $a$ over itself inductively.

Comment: Thanks, Asaf. With the intention to understand the notation: as you point out $g(f\upharpoonright n)=g(a_0,a_1,a_2)$ for $n=3$? And would $f(3)$ be a function from $4$ to $a$? And then is $h(f)$ $a\times a$ where the first $a$ comes from $g(a_0,a_1,a_2)$ and the second from $f(3+1)$? Sorry for so many probably dopy questions.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is a function from $4$ into $a$. So $f\restriction 3$ is some triplet $a_0,a_1$ and $a_2$. So $f(3)$ is the last coordinate of $f$.